# Convert date to fixed format python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

Team, I need help on converting date column in pandas dataframe. Below is how the date exists
`24-NOV-20 04.50.15.981213000 PM`.

I need it to convert to `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

Tried:

```py
     pd.to_datetime().dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').
```

```
But got ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '24-NOV-20 04.50.15.981213000 PM')
```

Comment: Try `pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: Getting error: ValueError: time data 24-NOV-20 04.50.15.981213000 PM doesn't match format specified

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
df['col'] = df['col'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```